# How to shorten the input field of a numeric input box without breaking label text?

Tags: r, shiny

How to shorten the input field of a numeric input box placed in a side panel such that long `label` text above it is not broken? Please, see the following example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(numericInput("num_input", "This is long text that should not be broken", value = 0)),
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I know that `numericInput` has a `width` argument, but shorten the box with it would lead to a line break in the `label` text, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css to style the `white-space` attribute of label element. In this case, I've done the styling inside a `div` tag:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # white-space: nowrap; ensures that the label doesn't wrap
      # as the app window becomes smaller
      div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 
          numericInput("num_input", "This is long text that should not be broken", 
              width = 280, value = 0)
          )
      ),
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```